# on form submission values not inserting into database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, phpmailer

i have an html form , when user submits the data, the data goes into database, this was working fine until i added one more thing, i added mail function to send the mail after the data is submitted. my code is like below:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);

session_start();
require('db_config.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 
 $name = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
 list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
 $image_name = time() . "." . $ext;
 $tmp = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];
 
 $shame = $_FILES['paymentphoto']['name'];
 list($txts, $exts) = explode(".", $shame);
 $receipt_name = time() . "." . $ext;
 $tmps = $_FILES['paymentphoto']['tmp_name'];
 
 if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'uploads/' . $image_name) && move_uploaded_file($tmps, 'receipt/' . $receipt_name)) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, image, company, designation, addressone, addresstwo, aadhar, city, state, pin, pan, rnameone, rnametwo, mobile, alternate, email, experience, businessdate, companyregistration, gstin, servicesoffered, fee, mode, receipt) VALUES ('" . $_POST['first_name'] . "','" . $_POST['last_name'] . "' , '" . $image_name . "','" . $_POST['company'] . "', '" . $_POST['designation'] . "','" . $_POST['address'] . "', '" . $_POST['address2'] . "', '" . $_POST['aadhaar'] . "', '" . $_POST['city'] . "', '" . $_POST['state'] . "', '" . $_POST['pin'] . "', '" . $_POST['pan'] . "', '" . $_POST['recommended'] . "', '" . $_POST['recommended2'] . "','" . $_POST['mobile'] . "', '" . $_POST['alternate'] . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', '" . $_POST['experience'] . "', '" . $_POST['date'] . "', '" . $_POST['registration'] . "', '" . $_POST['gst'] . "', '" . $_POST['services'] . "', '" . $_POST['fee'] . "', '" . $_POST['payment'] . "', '" . $receipt_name . "' )";
  $mysqli->query($sql);
  
  $to = "teiamembers@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
  $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  
  $headers = "From:" . $from . "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
  $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
  $subject = "TEIA Membership Registration Request";
  $subject2 = "TEIA Membership Request";
  $message = $first_name . " has requested for TEIA Registration.  Full Name:" . " " . $first_name . " " . $last_name . "<br>" . "Email:" . $from . "<br>" . "Mobile:" . " " . $_POST['mobile'] . "<br>" . "Company Name:" . " " . $_POST['company'] . "<br>" . "Designation" . " " . $_POST['designation'] . "<br>" . "Residence Address:" . " " . $_POST['address'] . "<br>" . "Office Address:" . " " . $_POST['address2'] . "<br>" . "Aadhaar:" . " " . $_POST['aadhaar'] . "<br>" . "City:" . " " . $_POST['city'] . "<br>" . "State:" . " " . $_POST['state'] . "<br>" . "Pin:" . " " . $_POST['pin'] . "<br>" . "Pan:" . " " . $_POST['pan'] . "<br>" . "Reference:" . " " . $_POST['recommended'] . "<br>" . "Alternate Number:" . " " . $_POST['alternate'] . "<br>" . "Experience:" . " " . $_POST['experience'] . "<br>" . "Aadhaar:" . " " . $_POST['aadhaar'] . "<br>" . "Date of Business Setup:" . " " . $_POST['date'] . "<br>" . "Company Registration Number:" . " " . $_POST['registration'] . "<br>" . "GSTIN:" . " " . $_POST['gst'] . "<br>" . "Services Offered:" . " " . $_POST['services'] . "<br>" . "Fee Paid:" . " " . $_POST['fee'] . "<br>" . "Payment Mode:" . " " . $_POST['payment'] . "<br>";
  $message2 = "Your request for TEIA Membership Received. We will contact you Shortly. ";
  
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
  
  if ($mysqli) {
   $msg = "Your Request For Membership Registration Sent Successfully";
  }
 }
}
?>
```

now the problem is when the user submits the form, the mail is working properly, but the values are not going to database, can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: Do these 2 conditions `move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'uploads/'.$image_name) && move_uploaded_file($tmps, 'receipt/'.$receipt_name)` evaluate true ?

Comment: you need to add error reporting enable. there is some warning or notice where query is getting failed and mail function works. or check your logs apache\logs\error.log and paste them here

Comment: @YomnaHesham yes

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TAKE CARE OF SQL INJECTION first.

Some amount of checking is necessary all the time. At the very least...this one.

```
if($mysqli->query($sql)) { fine } else { error }
```

And in the "error" part of above, if you would have included error number and actual message, you yourself might have found the answer.

Main doubt I have is...you have some unique column and the insert did not happen as it did appear in database earlier.

Also, better to use an id int unique auto_increment for several purposes.

Secondly, you should have created $mailstatus and have checked the same and not mysqli for this message.

```
if ($mailstatus) {
    $msg = "Your Request For Membership Registration Sent Successfully";
}
```